# Which JAR files are needed to use JSF 2.2 on WebSphere 8.5

Tags: jsf, websphere

I am using WebSphere 8.5 which has a default implementation of JSF 2.0.  I would like to use JSF 2.2.  I was trying to find out which JAR files should I be getting to have my application use JSF 2.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For MyFaces, you'll want `myfaces-impl` and `myfaces-api` as well its runtime dependencies `commons-beanutils`, `commons-collections`, `commons-digester`, and `commons-logging`.  For Mojarra, you'll just need `jsf-api` and `jsf-impl`.

Whichever implementation you use, make sure to follow the instructions for packaging third-party JSF implementations on WebSphere: 
[Configuring JavaServer Faces implementation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tweb_jsf.html)

Comment: Mojarra one seems to work for me.  I added the libraries in WEB-INF/lib though.